# Will this completely clean up the result of dynamic allocation of a class object?

Tags: c++, memory-management

So I dynamically allocated a class object with this code:

```
void Inventory::createNewInventoryItem(std::string itemName, unsigned int maxQuantity, unsigned int orderThreshold, double price)
{
    InventoryItems* newItem = new InventoryItems;
    newItem->createInventoryItem(itemName, maxQuantity, orderThreshold, price);
    m_inventory.push_back(newItem);
}
```

Which is stored in this vector: `std::vector<InventoryItems*> m_inventory;`

Then once the object is done being used `deleteInventoryItem` is called, which is defined as:

```
void Inventory::deleteInventoryItem(int posInVector)
{
    m_inventory.at(posInVector)->~InventoryItems();
    m_inventory.erase(m_inventory.begin() + posInVector);
}
```

My question is: Will this `deleteInventoryItem` function successfully free up the memory used by the dynamic allocation in `createNewInventoryItem`? (This ties into my confusion around if `delete[]` is needed when a class deconstructor is called)

Sorry for the not "Mission critical" question, just trying to make sure I'm not continuing bad practices as I'm really trying to program as perfectly as I could...

Comment: no it will leak. You are obvious calling the destructor but do not call `delete` which is the counterpart of `new`

Comment: The idiomatic C++-way would be to give `InventoryItems` a constructor that does what `createInventoryItem` does, store the items in the vector by value in a `std::vector<InventoryItems>`, create them via `m_inventory.emplace_back(itemName, ...)` and just erase them if you no longer need them. No nned for manual memeory management.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will this `deleteInventoryItem` function successfully free up the memory used by the dynamic allocation in `createNewInventoryItem`?

No, your code does leak memory. What you do here,

```
m_inventory.at(posInVector)->~InventoryItems();
```

is explicitly calling the destructor of the container element. This does clean up any resources held by the specific object, but not the memory resource that hosts the object itself. It is very, very rare that you have to manually call the destructor of an object (the only situation I can think of is using placement `new`, and you very rarely need that).

What you could have done is using `delete` to both clean up the memory *and* invoke the destructor of the element being erased. But as a much safer alternative for this manual memory management, I would advise you to choose one the following two options

1. If the object that is supposed to be stored in the container fine with being copied by value (i.e. not a polymorphic type and you want to store base class references), just store it by value:

   ```
   std::vector<InventoryItems> myData;
   ```
2. Otherwise, store a `std::unique_ptr` which takes care of all the memory managent for you:

   ```
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<InventoryItems>> myData;
   ```

Comment: *Slaps face* I completely forgot about smart pointers in this case... Also another dunce on my part I got the delete to work on just the single vector element(was not working before hence the above ^ attempt). Question @lubgr, so creating a vector of pointers would only be needed if its a polymorphic type?

Comment: For an example like this, yes, only when you have polymorphic types. But you can of course have scenarios where you want a collection of references that refer to an instance somewhere else - this could be `std::vector<MyType*>`, i.e., a vector of pointers. But the instances they refer to should rather by something like `std::vector<MyType>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>>` again.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your answers they really helped in understanding

Answer (score 1):

No it will memory-leak. You are obviously calling the destructor but do not call `delete` which is the counterpart of `new`. The `new` followed by a type allocates memory first then calls implicitly the destructor. The `delete` operator also does two things, first calling the destructor, then deallocate the memory.

There is rarely a need for explicitly calling the destructor, specifically for cleaning up instances created through the [`new` placement syntax.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), and not calling `~` it in this case will lead to leaks if the instance contains hold dynamically bound resources via members or base class(es).

As a rule of thumb, keep these pairs in mind:

- `obj = new Class;` needs `delete obj;`
- `obj = new (buffer) Class` needs `obj->~Class();`
- `array = new Class[count];` needs `delete [] array;`

... and, as the most important in the collection, automatic objects:

- `Class obj;` needs *`(nothing)`* <sup>*but the end of the enclosing scope*</sup>

The last "pair" shows an implicit call to (default) constructor (it could be any other constructor provided by the `Class` definition) and ends (at the closing brace) with an implicit call of the destructor, which, by the way, the reason for the C++ language to limit the destructors of a class to at maximum one: The compiler depends on this uniqueness to be able to automatically close scopes. This very automatism also forms the basis for [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).